# Recorrer Array con PHP para insertar valores en consulta SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

tengo el siguiente código:

```
if(isset($_POST['aplicar'])) {
                                $bafle = $_POST['bafle'];
                                $marca1 = $_POST['marca1'];
                                    if (is_array($marca1))
                                    {
                                      for ($i=0;$i<count($marca1);$i++)
                                      {
                                      }
                                    }
                                $size = $_POST['size'];
                                $j = 0;
                                foreach($size as $elemento)
                                {
                                   echo "$elemento<br>";
                                   ++$j;
                                }
                                $sistema = $_POST['sistema'];
                                $sql="SELECT * FROM `jsonBuscador` WHERE `tags` LIKE '%$marca1[0]$elemento$sistema%' OR `tags` LIKE '%$marca1[1]$elemento$sistema%'";
```

En el cual lo que estoy intentando hacer es obtener los datos enviados desde un formulario en forma de array, luego recorrer ese array e insertar los valores encontrados dentro del array en una consulta SQL, lamentablemente no puedo realizar dicha acción y quisiera que me pudieran ayudar, gracias.

Comment: necesitariamos ver como es el array que llega. Entiendo que te refieres al campo "marca1", que se supone sea un array, verdad? Si no sabes como mostrarlo, pon al principio del codigo print_r($_POST['marca1']);  para que te imprima por la pantalla como es el array. A partir de ahi vemos, ok?

Comment: Array ( [0] => PEAVEY [1] => DAS [2] => JPPROAUDIO ), este seria el array que me devuelve, la posición [0] y [1] ya las tengo definidas, pero al seleccionar mas opciones no logro hacer el recorrido, tengo que insertar dentro de la consulta SQL los valores del recorrido, ya sea uno, dos o tres.

Comment: @Jakala, puedes ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Qué API usas para la conexión, PDO o MySQLi? ¿Siempre viene tres datos en el array o pueden venir más o menos?

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo de concatenar los valores:

```
$values = [];

foreach([array] as [value]){
    $values .= " AND [column] = [value]";
}

$sth = $this->Connection->prepare("SELECT {$Select} FROM {$TableName} WHERE {$values}");
$sth->execute();
return $data = $sth->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```